# Ionic2 project using Backand fails at runtime with "TypeError: backand.init is not a function"

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, backand

My project has three pages with a tab in a tab navigation. The content fetched from the backend is wrapped in a provider that itself sets up a BackandService to fetch the date.

At runtime everything is fine at first. Data is fetched correctly on the default page. But the moment I do tab to another page that also uses the same provider the app crashes - I think something meant to be a Singleton is initialized a second time? If so, how do I import the providers without doing so? If not, where did I go wrong?

```
TypeError: backand.init is not a function
at BackandService.init (backand.service.js:16)
at new BackendWrapper (backend-wrapper.ts:19)
at AppModuleInjector.get (/AppModule/module.ngfactory.js:281)
at AppModuleInjector.get (/AppModule/module.ngfactory.js:286)
at AppModuleInjector.getInternal (/AppModule/module.ngfactory.js:397)
at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (ng_module_factory.js:94)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.injectorGet (view.js:109)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.injectorGet (view.js:351)
at ElementInjector.get (element_injector.js:24)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.injectorGet (view.js:109)
```

The actual imports look like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { BackandService } from '@backand/angular2-sdk';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class BackendWrapper {

  constructor(public http: Http,
    public backandService: BackandService) {

    this.backandService.init({
      appName: 'XXXXXX',
      anonymousToken: 'XXXXXXX'
    });
  }
...
}
```

and

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { BackendWrapper } from './backend-wrapper';
import { Auth } from './auth';


@Injectable()
export class ContentProvider {

...

  constructor(public http: Http,
              public auth: Auth,
              public backendWrap: BackendWrapper,
              public storage: Storage) {
    this.setUserSpecificsFromStorage();
  }
...
}
```

and

```
import { BackandService } from '@backand/angular2-sdk';
import { BackendWrapper } from '../providers/backend-wrapper';
import { ContentProvider } from '../providers/content-provider';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,

    ...
  ],
  providers: [Storage,
              Auth,
              BackandService,
              BackendWrapper,
              ContentProvider,
              {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}]
})
...
}
```

Comment: Please post some code where code is not working

Comment: I did add additional pieces of my code.

Comment: I did find a workaround by initializing the BackandService in app.component.ts instead of the wrapper but still don't know why this happens. Was I trying to initialize a Singleton twice or did I do a mistake regarding binding in Typescript/Javascript?